# Is there any Magento 2 extension for Google Recommendation AI

Tags: magento2, extensions, related-products, google-api, google-cloud

Last year, Google launched [AI & Machine Learning based Products Recommendations AI](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations). I'm dying to implement this on my Magento 2 site.

Is there an out-of-the-box extension for Magento 2 to integrate Google Recommendation AI? I've searched, but it seems none have developed yet.

Thank you, I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for the same. Have you stumbled upon something by any chance? At the We managed to put it online using Google Tag Manager. Abit of a hack of a setup but it's quick. Unfortunately the recommender shows only around 10% of the time. It's a good way for an initial test but unstable.